# EMBERJS : How to trigger an action in a child component?

Tags: ember.js, components, action

I know the concept of Data Down / Actions Up, but I'm facing a situation on which I don't know how to do it with the DDAU. I searched on differents forum and blogs how to do it, but it does not fit my request.

I have a controller with two components.
On the first component I have a header with a button.
On the second component I have a form.

When the button is clicked, an action is trigered and catched by the controller, but how can I notify the second component of the "click" on the button on the first component.

An easy solution would have been to include the first component in the second one, but I can't do this because each component are used in many different situations.

Comment: You *dont do this*! This is just against the DDAU pattern. Why does the second component even needs to know about that action? Write that code in the controller. I think we have the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: Why don't even use components if it can't do what the component should have to do and move this part of the behavior inside the controller just to be compliant with DDAU. My components **needs** to know about the action because the action must trigger changes (for exemple a refresh from an external ajax query, a save, ...). This is completly the responsability of my component and should not be delegated to the controler. And also, I don't want to duplicate the controler's code on each controler using this component.

Comment: Your first example, an AJAX request, is exactly something you probably shouldn't do in a component. If you usually use this form component and burton component side-by-side its probably best to create a third component containing the other two. That your code can sit in this surrounding component. Maybe you could join the slack channel to discuss this further.

Comment: I don't understand why it should be on a third component. It means each time I use this component, I'll have to create a new component to integrate/duplicate the behavior initially placed in the second component. IMHO, your are suggesting a solution in accordance with the DDAU, but which disagrees with the basic concept of components (isolation, responsabilities, code duplicate reduction, ..).

Comment: No, I don't. Either you have the same code all the time you use this component or not. If you have always the same code, and just want to replace the button, a wrapper component can save you. If it gets more complex [contextual components](https://ember-twiddle.com/2095e6091c62aeae369095c4ac3082d2?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-logic.hbs) come to the rescue. **If an action is not triggered inside an component it should not be handled in that component**. If you would describe your problem in more detail we probably could help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate our discussion. I've reviewed your code sample and I understand your point when you say a component should handle only actions triggered inside it. But, still, I think it could be much simplier if I could send the event of my button directly to the action of my form, and the logic of my component will be where it means to be : in my component. DDAU works fine but, in my opinion, implies some limitations or a higher complexity just to do basics things like : if I click here do that elsewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135042/discussion-between-luke77-and-lux).

Answer (score 3):

You can use services as a bus.

Register an event on second component and trigger that event from first component.

I show it in [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/43bb6a51df75cac3c46c34006770f51d)

If you don't want using services you can use parent-child model.

Please take a look at [that twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7018c6b68c7a78cfdcb3db49a5b3a8e6)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I could use this. I was hoping of somehting more "simple" than a bus to notify two sibling components..

Comment: Use a service to call a child action from parent controller. I needed this to wrap some code in child component. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `foo` property from controller to both components, and first component to pass action to controller to change `foo`. Now this sibling component too will be notified and you can make use of `didUpdateAttrs` hook in sibling component to react to change.

Comment: I thouh about this, using a data change to notify of an event, but I just can't decide to do this, I assume there's a better way to do that...

Comment: As Lux mentioned if possible its better to stay away from this kind of approach. IMHO.may be if you could explain use cases in your question, there might be better solutions you will get it.